# View outside screen

Tags: iphone, uiview, uiviewcontroller, interface-builder

I have a tab controller, which contains a navigation controller which again contains a view controller. The view controller shows a tab bar and a navigation bar.

In this view controller I want to add a full screen view (hides the tab bar and the navigation bar but leaves the status bar) which is shown during loading. I have subclassed UIView and set up a layout in a nib file which is loaded to this view:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame])
    {
        // Load nib
        self = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"FrontpageCountdownView" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
    }
}
```

I add this view in the view controller like this:

```
// Hide tab bar and navigation bar
self.tabBarController.tabBar.hidden = YES;
self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = YES;

// Add loading (frontpage countdown) view
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height);
NFFrontpageCountdownView *countdownView = [[NFFrontpageCountdownView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
[self.view addSubview:countdownView];
```

The view in my nib has a size of 460 (full screen, minus the status bar). My problem is, that when I add it to the view controller it appears "bigger".
I would think that since the view has a size of 460 it should show the entire view when it is added to the view controller but it doesn't show the bottom. It seems that the view is too big even though it is 460 pixels.

Can anybody tell me why this is?

[image: My view in Interface Builder]

**EDIT**

How my view looks in Interface Builder:

[image: My view in Interface Builder]

How my view looks in the simulator:

[image: My view in the simulator]

Comment: what values do you get if you log the 'frame' sizes ?

Comment: If I log the `frame`, I get `320.000000 x 460.000000 at 0.000000 ; 0.000000`. I have updated my question to show the difference between the view in Interface Builder and how it looks in the simulator.

Comment: I guess you have to sett the following line' view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
'

Comment: That will ruin my layout. I just don't understand why a height of 460 in Interface Builder isn't the same as a height of 460 "in code". If My view is 460 in Interface Builder but much higher when added as a subview.

Comment: I have tried removing the tab bar controller and the navigation controller and then adding the view in a plain view controller. That works perfectly. When I add a navigation controller to the view controller, it still works perfectly. Then, when adding a tab bar controller, the view "jumps". So, it's the tab bar controller messing it up. I will try to investigate this further.

Comment: It's the tab bar not being hidden correctly. It leaves a blank black spot. Notice the "extra space" between the bottom of the view and the Home button in the simulator. It's the 44px of the tab bar which is just black. Anyone know how to hide it correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens when hiding the tab bar using `self.tabBarController.tabBar.hidden = YES`.

Instead, you should hide it and then extend the view of the `tabBarController`.

```
CGRect tabBarFrame = self.tabBarController.view.frame;
tabBarFrame.size.height += self.tabBarController.tabBar.frame.size.height;
self.tabBarController.view.frame = tabBarFrame;
self.tabBarController.tabBar.hidden = YES;
```